# Magento: Compare Products link does not work

Tags: php, magento

My product comparison link doesn't work. This is in Magento 1.9.

[My issues are almost identical to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593345/compare-products-sidebar-item-doesnt-show-products), with the exception that clearing the index did not work. Is there anything else I can try?

Here are the issues:

When I click "Add to Compare" on a product, a message stating that "such-and-such product successfully added to compare list" appears.

However the compare products sidebar shows "You have no items to compare."

I can tell the table `catalog_compare_item` is being populated with the correct visitor ID and product ID, but if I do a `print_r($this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount())` in template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml, "0" is returned.

Why won't the sidebar show the products to compare?

Comment: Did you check that the products in your products listing are visible, enabled, and in stock?

Comment: yes, yes and yes! the products are all fine in every way. thanks for responding to this question!!

Comment: You are welcome. Have a lovely day.

Comment: Did you check database tables: catalog_compare_item and report_compared_product_index if they get populated when adding to compare happens?
Check against the visitor ID which you can get from Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() and the product ID or if you are logged in, you can check against the logged in Customer.

Comment: @zokibtmkd Thanks for this help! Ok, yeah, `catalog_compare_item` is being populated with the correct visitor ID and product ID - but `$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount()` still returns 0. I cant find a table called `report_compared_product_index` however, could this be my problem?

Comment: The table report_compared_product_index is added by the Mage/Reports core module. It uses an Observer model to populate this table when add to compare happens. Then in template/reports/product_compared.phtml  (This is in the sidebar) it uses this table to print out the recently compared products. As for the $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount() is using method called "calculate" to get the number of items, I would put some logs in there to see what's going on. Try adding to compare with logged in customer and without and see how it behaves.

Comment: no difference when logged in / out - im guessing this product_compared.phtml is on the front end - what renders this file (i did a search of the layout folder and found nothing).

Comment: @Jimmery: what is your product type ? Simple, bundle or ...

Comment: most of my products on the site are configurable

Comment: Does it work when you disable all caches?

Comment: i have disabled all the caches and re-indexed over and over again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like your Magento DB does not have report_compared_product_index table.

Import the following SQL to create this table structure in your DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `report_compared_product_index` (
`index_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Index Id',
  `visitor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Added At'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reports Compared Product Index Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`visitor_id`,`product_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`customer_id`,`product_id`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID` (`store_id`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT` (`added_at`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Make sure you have "report_compared_product_index" table in your database.

Step 2 : clearing cache and perform indexing

step 3 : go to the following url

```html
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare.php
```

Find the following function

```html
public function calculate($logout = false)
```

and commenting the code as bellow

```html
 // first visit
       // if  (!$this->_catalogSession->hasCatalogCompareItemsCount() && !$this->_customerId) {
//            $count = 0;
  //      } else {
            /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Compare_Item_Collection */
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection')
                ->useProductItem(true);
            if (!$logout && $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $collection->setCustomerId($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
            } elseif ($this->_customerId) {
                $collection->setCustomerId($this->_customerId);
            } else {
                $collection->setVisitorId($this->_logVisitor->getId());
            }

            /* Price data is added to consider item stock status using price index */
            $collection->addPriceData();

            $this->_productVisibility->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($collection);

            $count = $collection->getSize();
       // }

        $this->_catalogSession->setCatalogCompareItemsCount($count);

        return $this;
```

Let me know if you have still any query

Thanks

Sagar